# mod_rewrite issues

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have used the `mod_rewrite` module but was not able to redirect to the target page - I am getting an error:

> The requested URL /old.html was not found on this server.

Rewrite rules as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/IN/index.html$ /IN/index.iface [L]
```

Comment: Where's `old.html`? What URL are you using to get that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request a URL with a path that’s matched by the pattern of your `RewriteRule` directive. So in your case obviously `/IN/index.html` (where the `.` can actually be any character, as it’s not escaped).